Change the color of individual words in a word document using python
I'd like to highlight by changing the font color words in a word document from a list before saving the word document as a new document.
def highlight_words(document, words):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            for word in words:
                if word in run.text:
                    for txt in run._element.iter("t"):
                        if word in txt.text:
                            txt.text = txt.text.replace(word, '')
                            new_run = run._element
                            r = new_run.getparent()
                            rPr = r.get_or_add_rPr()
                            rPr.color = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)

This is the relevant function for the highlighting. However, it fails to highlight any of the words. I've tried several different ways from chat gpt and stack overflow, but each one has either fed an error, highlighted entire sentences or paragraphs, or fed me gobbly gook.
def analyze(filename):
    causal_words_to_highlight = ["and", "then"]  # Hardcoded words to highlight
    weak_words_to_highlight = ["got", "gots", "put", "really", "very", "said", "good", "bad", "go", "going", "went", "come", "comes", "came", "say", "said", "get", "got", "see", "saw", "nice", "mean", "pretty", "ugly", "big", "a lot", "fun", "well", "little", "fast", "slow", "big", "small", "interesting", "fetid", "really"]
    there_words_to_highlight = ["There is", "There was", "There are", "There were"]
    story = import_story(filename)
    if story is not None:
        doc = Document()

        # Add each paragraph to the new document and highlight words
        for paragraph_text in story.split("\n"):
            paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
            paragraph.add_run(paragraph_text)

        # Highlight specific words in the document
        words_to_highlight = causal_words_to_highlight + weak_words_to_highlight + there_words_to_highlight + ["just"]
        highlight_words(doc, words_to_highlight)

        # Save the modified document
        doc.save(f"{filename[:-5]}_highlighted.docx")

This is the relevant portion of the analyze function.
All help is appreciated

for txt in run._element.iter("t"): can't get any value. You can try print(txt.text)

I solved it.Just modify highlight_words.
def highlight_words(document, words):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            for word in words:
                if word in run.text:
                    run.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(255, 0, 0)


I tried that and it highlighted entire paragraphs rather than just the individual word.

Can you share a part of your docx text?

Vaarash opened his eyes slowly. The metal ceiling of his apartment greeted him. He rose slowly at first then he excitedly remembered what today was. He paused as he looked at the bag he had collected. Meager belongings for over five hundred years alive. He paused looking at a picture of him with his parents. A bittersweet smile graced his face. He also placed it in the bag. Over the past few months he had carefully stashed away enough supplements to last him quite some time. He fingered the metallic pills he had snuck from the kitchen. Some food also joined them.

Its just a chapter from a story that I am writing that I use for testing, this entire paragraph is highlighted.
